# Mail not responding when syncing with Google Apps Gmail account in OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

Mail.app goes unresponsive whenever a specific Gmail account is added.

If I quit the process and go to `System Preferences > Internet Accounts` and disable the account, I can start Mail normally.

I can then use my other accounts (Exchange and Gmail) normally. If I then go to `Preferences` and enable the offending Gmail account, new emails are downloaded and then mail goes unresponsive.

I have tried removing and recreating the internet account, the mailbox, etc. I can verify that Mail downloads 1.5GB of data (approximately the size of the Gmail account) whenever I recreate the account. It remains unresponsive whenever the account is active.

I have tried the solution laid out [here](https://www.davescomputers.com/problems-gmail-mac-yosemite/). It worked the first time this happened and now did not resolve the issue.

Can anyone think of any other steps to take to reset mail and get this issue fixed? Does anyone know the source of the bug?

Comment: did you try to disable all but Inbox IMAP folders in gmail web?

Comment: Yes, no noticeable difference.  Mail.app still goes to "Not Responding" after downloading new inbox emails.

Comment: when you enable that gmail go to Mail - Window - Open the Activity and see it work. Does it eventually stop? if there is no activity that window will be empty.

Comment: Just magically started working after I added back only "All Mail" for the "Show in IMAP" setting for Gmail Labels.  Which I have done several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off all "Show in IMAP" label settings in the Gmail web console.
[image]

I then added back only "All Mail."  I restarted Mail.app and reenabled the account. 
Mail started normally and my email was available.

I still would like to know the source of the issue, but for now the problem is resolved.